# How to check in Servlet if request.getParameterValues has empty data

Tags: arrays, servlets, is-empty

My form:

```
<form action="/parvaz.aero/InsertUserCategories" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="category" placeholder="">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="category" placeholder="">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="category" placeholder="">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="category" placeholder="">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="category" placeholder="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My Servlet is getting values either its null, empty or data.

```
String[] category = request.getParameterValues("category");
```

Checking in Servlet as:

```
if (null != category && category.length > 0) {
    try {
        //insert in DB
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        
    }           
} else {
    out.println("There is no data to insert in DB";
}
```

When write: `out.print(category.length);` by sending the html form empty its giving result as:

> 5

Why the servlet assuming empty form length as `5` whereas it's received without any data?

How do I know it's empty or has data?

Comment: Hi add `[]` after `category` i.e : `name="category[]"` for all inputs and see if that works

Comment: I added but now its throwing error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "categories" is null`

Comment: Hi where is `categories` ? because in your provided code its `category`

Comment: when I tried as category[0] 1, 2.... then its not throwing error but not passing / checking anything even not getting

Comment: sorry I written  category not categories that is typo. am I write its should be added in my HTML code?

Comment: @Swati I updated my question and added the code working on it. Now NullPointerException is not throwing but hanged in else block of if statement

Comment: change `null != category` to `category != null`  . Also , print `out.println(category.length)` see what it gives

Comment: category.length prints `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "category" is null` I changed to `category !=null` but no change

Comment: @BalusC Now the problem become clear to me that on submitting empty form without data is assuming its length to 5 and boolean type true that's why my servlet is unable to add any null check. Please advise how to fix it?

Comment: @BalusC I removed the updated part and re-written my question as simple as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that you expected that a form submit with 5 empty fields of same name would give you a `null` or empty array. This is indeed not true. This will just send an array of 5 empty strings.

Only the complete absence of input field will give you `null`.

```xml
<form>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```java
String input = request.getParameter("input");
System.out.println(input); // null
System.out.println(input == null); // true

String[] inputs = request.getParameterValues("inputs");
System.out.println(inputs); // null
System.out.println(inputs == null); // true
```

Submit of an empty field will give you an empty string.

```xml
<form>
    <input name="input" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```java
String input = request.getParameter("input");
System.out.println(input); // empty string
System.out.println(input == null); // false
System.out.println(input.isEmpty()); // true

String[] inputs = request.getParameterValues("input");
System.out.println(inputs == null); // false
System.out.println(inputs.length); // 1
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputs)); // []
System.out.println(inputs[0].isEmpty()); // true
```

Submit of empty fields will give you an array of empty strings.

```xml
<form>
    <input name="input" />
    <input name="input" />
    <input name="input" />
    <input name="input" />
    <input name="input" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```java
String[] inputs = request.getParameterValues("input");
System.out.println(inputs == null); // false
System.out.println(inputs.length); // 5
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputs)); // [, , , , ]
System.out.println(inputs[0].isEmpty()); // true
System.out.println(inputs[1].isEmpty()); // true
System.out.println(inputs[2].isEmpty()); // true
System.out.println(inputs[3].isEmpty()); // true
System.out.println(inputs[4].isEmpty()); // true
```

You basically need to adjust your precondition as follows:

```java
if (inputs != null) {
    for (String input : inputs) {
        if (!input.isEmpty()) {
            // This input is not empty. Process it.
        }
    }
}
```

If you'd like to check beforehand if *all* inputs are null or empty, then do so:

```java
if (inputs == null) {
    // Inputs were not included in form.
}
else if (Arrays.stream(inputs).allMatch(String::isEmpty)) {
    // Inputs were included in form, but they are all empty.
}
else {
    // At least one input is included in form and not empty.
}
```

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart. I spent 2 days but was not able to fix it. Appreciated!!

Comment: I just clean the project and its started throwing error `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0`. May I add a new question?

Comment: It's not related to processing form parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException%20%22String%20index%20out%20of%20range%22

Comment: Ok Sir. Thank you very much